# Error while using GPU on UNET with FLUX in Julia

Tags: julia, gpu, flux.jl, unet-neural-network

I'm using Julia for UNet training with GPU. (Runs without issues on CPU).
The error is at NNlib's function conv_im2col()

```
function conv_im2col!(
                y::AbstractArray{T,5}, x::AbstractArray{T,5},
                w::AbstractArray{T,5}, cdims::DenseConvDims;
                col::AbstractArray{T,3}=similar(x, im2col_dims(cdims)),
                alpha::T=T(1), beta::T=T(0)) where {T}
    check_dims(size(x), size(w), size(y), cdims)

    #   COL   *    W    ->    Y
    # [M x K] * [K x N] -> [M x N]
    #
    #  M: output spatial resolution
    #  N: output channels
    #  K: size of input "patch" (kernel size and input channels combined)
    #
    # In english, we're grabbing each input patch and laying them out along
    # the M dimension in `col`, so that the GEMM call below multiplies each
    # kernel (which is kernel_h * kernel_w * channels_in elments long) is
    # dotproducted with that input patch, effectively computing a convolution
    # in a somewhat memory-wasteful but easily-computed way (since we already
    # have an extremely highly-optimized GEMM call available in BLAS).
    M = prod(output_size(cdims))
    N = channels_out(cdims)
    K = prod(kernel_size(cdims))*channels_in(cdims)

    @threads for batch_idx in 1:size(x,5)
        # col_slice is a thread-local workspace
        col_slice = view(col, :, :, threadid())

        im2col!(col_slice, view(x, :, :, :, :, batch_idx), cdims)
        GC.@preserve col_slice w y begin
            col_ptr = pointer(col_slice)
            w_ptr = pointer(w)
            y_ptr = pointer(y, (batch_idx - 1)*M*N + 1)
            gemm!(Val(false), Val(false), M, N, K, alpha, col_ptr, w_ptr, beta, y_ptr)
        end
```

and the detailed error is:

> [ Info: training... [ Info: Using Device gpu Epoch    Minibatch Loss
> Test Dice Coef
> ---------------------------------------------- 1ERROR: LoadError: TaskFailedException
>
> ```
> nested task error: TaskFailedException
> Stacktrace:
>  [1] wait
>    @ ./task.jl:322 [inlined]
>  [2] threading_run(func::Function)
>    @ Base.Threads ./threadingconstructs.jl:34
>  [3] macro expansion
>    @ ./threadingconstructs.jl:93 [inlined]
>  [4] conv_im2col!(y::SubArray{Float32, 5, Array{Float32, 5}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> ```
>
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, UnitRange{Int64},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false}, x::SubArray{Float32, 5,
> Array{Float32, 5}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> UnitRange{Int64}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false},
> w::CuArray{Float32, 5, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, cdims::DenseConvDims{3,
> 3, 3, 6, 3}; col::Array{Float32, 3}, alpha::Float32, beta::Float32)
> @ NNlib ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/impl/conv_im2col.jl:47

> ```
>  [5] conv_im2col! @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/impl/conv_im2col.jl:28 [inlined]
> ```

> ```
>  [6] (::NNlib.var"#262#266"{Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(), Tuple{}}}, DenseConvDims{3, 3, 3, 6, 3},
> ```
>
> SubArray{Float32, 5, Array{Float32, 5},
> Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, UnitRange{Int64},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false}, CuArray{Float32, 5,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, SubArray{Float32, 5, Array{Float32, 5},
> Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, UnitRange{Int64},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false}})()
> @ NNlib ./threadingconstructs.jl:169
>
> ```
>     nested task error: MethodError: no method matching gemm!(::Val{false}, ::Val{false}, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64,::Float32, ::Ptr{Float32}, ::CuPtr{Float32}, ::Float32, ::Ptr{Float32})
>     Closest candidates are:
>       gemm!(::Val, ::Val, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float32, ::Ptr{Float32}, ::Ptr{Float32}, ::Float32, ::Ptr{Float32}) at
> ```
>
> .julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/gemm.jl:29
> gemm!(::Val, ::Val, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::Ptr{Float64}, ::Ptr{Float64}, ::Float64, ::Ptr{Float64}) at
> .julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/gemm.jl:29
> gemm!(::Val, ::Val, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::ComplexF64, ::Ptr{ComplexF64}, ::Ptr{ComplexF64}, ::ComplexF64, ::Ptr{ComplexF64})
> at .julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/gemm.jl:29
> ...
> Stacktrace:
> [1] macro expansion
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/impl/conv_im2col.jl:56 [inlined]
> [2] (::NNlib.var"#909#threadsfor_fun#504"{Array{Float32, 3}, Float32, Float32, SubArray{Float32, 5, Array{Float32, 5},
> Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, UnitRange{Int64},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false}, SubArray{Float32, 5,
> Array{Float32, 5}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> UnitRange{Int64}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false},
> CuArray{Float32, 5, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, DenseConvDims{3, 3, 3, 6,
> 3}, Int64, Int64, Int64, UnitRange{Int64}})(onethread::Bool)
> @ NNlib ./threadingconstructs.jl:81
> [3] (::NNlib.var"#909#threadsfor_fun#504"{Array{Float32, 3}, Float32, Float32, SubArray{Float32, 5, Array{Float32, 5},
> Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, UnitRange{Int64},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false}, SubArray{Float32, 5,
> Array{Float32, 5}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}},
> UnitRange{Int64}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, false},
> CuArray{Float32, 5, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, DenseConvDims{3, 3, 3, 6,
> 3}, Int64, Int64, Int64, UnitRange{Int64}})()
> @ NNlib ./threadingconstructs.jl:48 Stacktrace:   [1] sync_end(c::Channel{Any})
> @ Base ./task.jl:369   [2] macro expansion
> @ ./task.jl:388 [inlined]   [3] conv!(out::Array{Float32, 5}, in1::Array{Float32, 5}, in2::CuArray{Float32, 5,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, cdims::DenseConvDims{3, 3, 3, 6, 3};
> kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(),
> Tuple{}}})
> @ NNlib ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:195   [4] conv!
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:186 [inlined]   [5] conv!(y::Array{Float32, 4}, x::Array{Float32, 4}, w::CuArray{Float32,
> 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, cdims::DenseConvDims{2, 2, 2, 4, 2};
> kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(),
> Tuple{}}})
> @ NNlib ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:145   [6] conv!
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:145 [inlined]   [7] conv(x::Array{Float32, 4}, w::CuArray{Float32, 4,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, cdims::DenseConvDims{2, 2, 2, 4, 2};
> kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{}, Union{}, Tuple{}, NamedTuple{(),
> Tuple{}}})
> @ NNlib ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:88   [8] conv
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:86 [inlined]   [9] #rrule#312
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:313 [inlined]  [10] rrule
> @ ~/.julia/packages/NNlib/0QnJJ/src/conv.jl:304 [inlined]  [11] rrule
> @ ~/.julia/packages/ChainRulesCore/ctmSK/src/rules.jl:134 [inlined]  [12] chain_rrule
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/chainrules.jl:218 [inlined]  [13] macro expansion
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0 [inlined]  [14] _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:9 [inlined]  [15] _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/layers/conv.jl:200 [inlined]  [16] macro expansion
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/layers/basic.jl:53 [inlined]  [17] _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/layers/basic.jl:53 [inlined]  [18] _pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::typeof(Flux._applychain),
> ::WARNING: both Losses and NNlib export "ctc_loss"; uses of it in
> module Flux must be qualified Tuple{Conv{2, 2, typeof(identity),
> CuArray{Float32, 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(selu), CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Conv{2, 2, typeof(identity), CuArray{Float32,
> 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(selu), CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}, ::Array{Float32, 4})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0  [19]
> _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/layers/basic.jl:51 [inlined]  [20] _pullback(ctx::Zygote.Context{true}, f::Chain{Tuple{Conv{2, 2,
> typeof(identity), CuArray{Float32, 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer},
> CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(selu),
> CuArray{Float32, 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CuArray{Float32,
> 1, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, Conv{2, 2, typeof(identity),
> CuArray{Float32, 4, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}, BatchNorm{typeof(selu), CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}, Float32, CuArray{Float32, 1,
> CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}}}, args::Array{Float32, 4})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0  [21]
> _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/dev/UNet/src/model.jl:93 [inlined]  [22] _pullback(ctx::Zygote.Context{true}, f::Unet, args::Array{Float32, 4})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0  [23]
> _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/dev/UNet/src/train.jl:37 [inlined]  [24] _pullback(::Zygote.Context{true}, ::UNet.var"#loss#75"{typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy), Unet},
> ::Array{Float32, 4}, ::Array{Int32, 4})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0  [25]
> _apply
> @ ./boot.jl:804 [inlined]  [26] adjoint
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/lib/lib.jl:203 [inlined]  [27] _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/ZygoteRules/AIbCs/src/adjoint.jl:65 [inlined]  [28] _pullback
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/optimise/train.jl:120 [inlined]  [29] _pullback(::Zygote.Context{true},
> ::Flux.Optimise.var"#37#40"{UNet.var"#loss#75"{typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy),
> Unet}, Tuple{Array{Float32, 4}, Array{Int32, 4}}})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface2.jl:0  [30]
> pullback(f::Function, ps::Zygote.Params{Zygote.Buffer{Any,
> Vector{Any}}})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface.jl:373  [31]
> gradient(f::Function, args::Zygote.Params{Zygote.Buffer{Any,
> Vector{Any}}})
> @ Zygote ~/.julia/packages/Zygote/xGkZ5/src/compiler/interface.jl:96  [32]
> macro expansion
> @ ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/optimise/train.jl:119 [inlined]  [33] macro expansion
> @ ~/.julia/packages/ProgressLogging/6KXlp/src/ProgressLogging.jl:328
> [inlined]  [34] train!(loss::Function,
> ps::Zygote.Params{Zygote.Buffer{Any, Vector{Any}}},
> data::MLUtils.DataLoader{Tuple{Array{Float32, 4}, Array{Int32, 4}},
> Random._GLOBAL_RNG}, opt::RMSProp; cb::UNet.var"#77#78"{Unet,
> MLUtils.DataLoader{Tuple{Array{Float32, 4}, Array{Int32, 4}},
> Random._GLOBAL_RNG}})
> @ Flux.Optimise ~/.julia/packages/Flux/KkC79/src/optimise/train.jl:117  [35]
> train(train_dataset::ImageDataset, test_dataset::ImageDataset,
> model::Unet, opt::RMSProp,
> loss::UNet.var"#loss#75"{typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy), Unet};
> batch_size::Int64, num_epochs::Int64,
> learning_rate_drop_rate::Float64, learning_rate_step::Int64,
> device::Function, save_intermediate_models::Bool, save_model::Bool,
> out_dir::String, model_file_name::String)
> @ UNet ~/.julia/dev/UNet/src/train.jl:123  [36] train(train_dataset::ImageDataset, test_dataset::ImageDataset,
> num_channels::Int64, num_labels::Int64;
> loss_function::typeof(Flux.Losses.logitcrossentropy),
> learning_rate::Float64, momentum::Float64, device::Function,
> kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol, Any, NTuple{6, Symbol},
> NamedTuple{(:num_epochs, :batch_size, :save_intermediate_models,
> :save_model, :out_dir, :model_file_name), Tuple{Int64, Int64, Bool,
> Bool, String, String}}})
> @ UNet ~/.julia/dev/UNet/src/train.jl:40  [37] top-level scope
> @ /train_images.jl:70  [38] include(fname::String)
> @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:444  [39] top-level scope
> @ REPL[2]:1 in expression starting at  train_images.jl:70